# List of services affected by the Apache Log4jshell Vulnerability

Tags: tomcat, java, solr, vulnerability, log4j

Does there yet exist a list of software that is potentially affected by the **Apache Log4jshell** vulnerability ([CVE-2021-44228](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2021-44228)) that was announced last Friday?

As someone managing a number of servers with lots of different software running on them it would be nice to have a list of potentially affected software. Not something overly detailed with versions, just anything with any affected version or even anything that *might* be affected.

To start off the list:

- Apache Solr
- Apache Tomcat
- Apache Struts
- Apache Druid
- Apache Flink
- Apache Swift
- Elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

After further research I've found the following two lists which are being actively updated with information about possibly affected software:

CISA: https://github.com/cisagov/log4j-affected-db

NCSC: https://github.com/NCSC-NL/log4shell/blob/main/software/README.md

Please comment, edit, or add another answer with any other useful lists.